# Excel Pivot Table: If cell is blank, use a different cell

Tags: excel, pivot

So I have a pivot table which shows the owners name and the mileage of their car.
Sometimes in my data-set there is no owner name - how do you account for this, and be able to re-direct it to a different cell.

So if owner name is blank, then utilise the car brand name instead for that row, so that it never uses (blank).

Comment: Can you include a schematic (not as a picture) of dataset and/or pivot table in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a new helper column, filling in a value in case of blank, something like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"BLANCO",A2)
```

This gives following result:

```
Col1      Col2 (containing the formula)
====      ====
   a         a   
   b         b
        BLANCO
   d         d
```

Comment: Ahhh, I knew it must've been something as simple as this - silly me, thank you!